# Count unsigned integers less than a given unsigned integer with same number of set bits

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, bitset

Is there an efficient way to count all unsigned integers less than a given unsigned integer with the same amount of set bits?

**What I've tried so far**

Given an unsigned integer represented as a list of set bits in descending order, I can use colex functions to count smaller unsigned integers with the same number of set bits. I've implemented both a recursive process (to show the logic) and an iterative process below in Python 3.

Idea came from [this paper](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~./waugh/publications/isomorphism13.pdf).

I'd rather have a solution that didn't rely on the bits being sorted.

```
from math import factorial


def n_choose_k(n, k):
    return 0 if n < k else factorial(n) // (factorial(k) * factorial(n - k))


def indexset_recursive(bitset, lowest_bit=0):
    """Return number of bitsets with same number of set bits but less than
    given bitset.

    Args:
      bitset (sequence) - Sequence of set bits in descending order.
      lowest_bit (int) - Name of the lowest bit. Default = 0.

    >>> indexset_recursive([51, 50, 49, 48, 47, 46, 45])
    133784559
    >>> indexset_recursive([52, 51, 50, 49, 48, 47, 46], lowest_bit=1)
    133784559
    >>> indexset_recursive([6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0])
    0
    >>> indexset_recursive([7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1], lowest_bit=1)
    0

    """
    m = len(bitset)
    first = bitset[0] - lowest_bit
    if m == 1:
        return first
    else:
        t = n_choose_k(first, m)
        return t + indexset_recursive(bitset[1:], lowest_bit)


def indexset(bitset, lowest_bit=0):
    """Return number of bitsets with same number of set bits but less than
    given bitset.

    Args:
      bitset (sequence) - Sequence of set bits in descending order.
      lowest_bit (int) - Name of the lowest bit. Default = 0.

   >>> indexset([51, 50, 49, 48, 47, 46, 45])
    133784559
    >>> indexset([52, 51, 50, 49, 48, 47, 46], lowest_bit=1)
    133784559
    >>> indexset([6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0])
    0
    >>> indexset([7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1], lowest_bit=1)
    0

    """
    m = len(bitset)
    g = enumerate(bitset)
    return sum(n_choose_k(bit - lowest_bit, m - i) for i, bit in g)
```

Comment: Any reason you couldn't just sort the list of bit indices and pass it to your existing functions?

Comment: Speed. Can't afford sort.

Comment: Well, I don't know your exact use case, but I'm thinking that if you have such stringent performance requirements that you can't afford sorting a short list of integers, you probably shouldn't be using Python.

Comment: Python = pseudocode/prototype. Would either run on pypy or translate using cython.